# Getting Denied Apache2

Tags: php, linux, http, apache2

I am constanly getting denied to access pages on my website. I rsync(ed) over my old website to a new SLES12 server. I tried changing permissions and I am still getting denied. Most of the pages are php but I am unable to access them either.

My server says PHP is installed.

Any advice?

Permission denied: [client 172.16.1.175:51697] AH00035: access to /favicon.ico denied (filesystem path '/srv/www/htdocs/favicon.icon

Comment: Have you commisioned the new server yourself? Could it be an issue with [SELinux](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:SELinux)?

Answer (score 0):

Which user is apache running as? Check that the apache user has read access to your web files e.g. `chown/chgrp ${apche_user} -R /srv/www/htdocs`

Are you using virtual hosts?

Have you tried disabling SELinux ?

Comment: I created the server myself. SELINUX is not installed and I am not using virtual hosts.

Comment: The firewall is also off. I tried changing the group and owner but still nothing.

Comment: [Wed May 11 21:41:26.797883 2016] [core:error] [pid 2322] (13)Permission denied: [client 192.168.1.46:55671] AH00035: access to /favicon.ico denied (filesystem path '/srv/www/htdocs/favicon.ico') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path, referer: http://10.100.0.148/

Comment: @MichaelW. Your file permissions are wrong on either `/srv/www` or `/srv/www/htdocs`, missing a `+x`. See https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied

Comment: Thank you DaSourcerer, that seems to be better but when I do index.php it is downloading the file instad of displaying

Comment: I found the issue. SLES12 there is a web and scripting module I needed to add.